# I Created A Dialog, Now How Can I Close It?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have included a link to my site below for review of the JS in the head section, as well as to allow YOU to see how I set it all up. If you don't want to use the link, I'll also try to include the code below.

I recently learned some basic AJAX and on select pages of my site  http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/detail.php?fatherID=37&TypeID=42&ListingID=42 I have created a dialog that you'll see appear onscroll.

If someone could please share with me how I can make the close button close the dialog box I'd be most appreciative.

Here's the JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loaddiv(thediv, thefile) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject ('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById(thediv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', thefile, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Then on the page I only have

```
echo "<div id='div2'></div>";
```

Then for the box that pops up:

```
<div class="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox">
<h2>Got A Dirt Bike You Want to Sell?</h2>
<p class="DirtBikeForSaleBannerButton">
<a href="http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/add.php">Yea, Show Me How</a>
</p>

<p class="DirtBikeForSaleBannerButtonNoThanks">
<a href="CloseDialog">Nope, Get This Out of The Way</a>
</p> 
</div>
```

If anyone could share with me how I can make this dialog box disappear with a click of the close button I'd be most appreciative and I'd like to thank you all in advance.

Thanks,

Stuart K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can try this:

```
<div class="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox" id="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox">
    <h2>Got A Dirt Bike You Want to Sell?</h2>
    <p class="DirtBikeForSaleBannerButton">
    <a href="http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/add.php">Yea, Show Me How</a>
    </p>

    <p class="DirtBikeForSaleBannerButtonNoThanks">
    <a onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox').style.visibility='hidden';">Nope, Get This Out of The Way</a>

    </p> 
</div>
```

Tested on my localhost xD

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*EDITED****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Better try this and see if the scroll doesnt show the div again:

```
<div class="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox" id="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox">
    <h2>Got A Dirt Bike You Want to Sell?</h2>
    <p class="DirtBikeForSaleBannerButton">
    <a href="http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/add.php">Yea, Show Me How</a>
    </p>

    <p class="DirtBikeForSaleBannerButtonNoThanks">
    <a onclick="javascript:var div = document.getElementById('DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox');div.parentNode.removeChild(div);">Nope, Get This Out of The Way</a>
```

----------------------------UPDATE2---------------------------------

```
   <div id='div2'>
    <div class="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox" id="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox">
    <h2>Got A Dirt Bike You Want to Sell?</h2>
    <p class="DirtBikeForSaleBannerButton">
    <a href="http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/add.php">Yea, Show Me How</a>
    </p>

    <p class="DirtBikeForSaleBannerButtonNoThanks">
    <a onclick="javascript:var div = document.getElementById('div2');div.parentNode.removeChild(div);">Nope, Get This Out of The Way</a>

    </p> 
    </div>
    </div>
```

Saludos ;)

Comment: Thank You So Much Robert Rozas!!! I'll be using this bit of code and I thank you very very much for your help!!

Comment: Side Note: I really appreciate all of your help. I presume that this question was very basic but if you don't know what to do, you simply DONT know what to do and things become very difficult. Thanks once again everyone

Comment: Hmmm... New problem, After implementing the code that Robert Rozas provided the box goes away but since I call the function that displays this box in the body  tag onscroll, the box reappears after I close  it and begin to scroll. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Robert, I'm new to SO so I missed this comment box whereas I could comment behind you and (hopefully) you'll see it. I tried this updated code but am still having troubles. (Please see my most recent post(s) below)

Comment: Hi Again Robert, During the time since my last post until I had seen your most recent post I have been playing with integrating a hit counter tutorial I had seen in the past into what I'm trying to do with this dialog. Unfortunately, (so it doesn't get lost amid all these responses) I am going to create a new thread with code samples and all. I do hope you'll take a look at the new thread and advise because with the extra functionality I added to the script, I no longer know how to use the updated code you provided a second time. Link to new thread to come...

Comment: Ok...post here the link to the new thread and i'll be there ;)

Comment: Here's a link to the new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532360/second-part-to-dialog-closing

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it from the dom using

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

or you can set the display style of the element to 'none' and then  you can play with it and create open-close

Comment: Wow... You make it sound so easy... LOL. I thank you for your help but I don't have a clue where I would include the bit of code you provided, OR how I would tie it to the "Close" button. If you could slightly elaborate on this I'd really appreciate it and I thank you once again.

Comment: Ya'll Rock!! Sorry, I had only seen Adidi's comment before I had posted again. Please disregard my last comment, I'll be working on interpreting the code Jordan and armandocj provided. Thanks Guys!!

Comment: If your popup dialog is eventually in some element container right? so you can set on that element display none or block. or you can remove that element from the dom. lets say the element id is "divy" then var el = document.getElementById('divy');el.parentNode.removeChild(el); will do the trick

Comment: Hi Everyone, One more question regarding this: Can anyone think of a way I could prevent this from showing more than once for a visitor?? I was thinking of doing something like this: When a visitor clicks the close button this would then record their IP address, then on subsequent visits (or visits to another page on the site) this loaddiv function would check for the visitor's IP address and if found would NOT display the dialog. But is there an easier way??

Comment: DUMB QUESTION ALERT: How do I call the CloseDialog function without going to another URL?? I Tried the code below but am unsuccessful:<p class="DirtBikeForSaleBannerButtonNoThanks">
<a onclick="CloseDialog()">Nope, Get This Out of The Way</a>
</p>

Comment: Hi Robert, I really appreciate your help and I apologize for the delay in my response. I tried your edited code above, yet the box returns upon scrolling. Should you or anyone have any other ideas I'm all ears. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: I'd like to add that when I hover over the left button I get a hand for a cursor (as if clickable) but when I hover over the "Nope, Get This Out of the Way", the pointer turns to an "I" bar (looks like a cursor over a text entry field) I don't know if this means something else is wrong in the code and that's why the box reappears after closing and scrolling??

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show it again, you could call

`document.getElementById('div2').remove();`

in the onclick method of the close button.

Or if you might use it again, call

`document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';`

To call the close function from the href attribute:

`<a href="javascript: CloseDialog();">Nope, Get This Out of The Way</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery, you could do it with the "live" method. That will attach event handlers to any new elements that appear on the page even after an ajax request. So if you gave the close bit a class:

```
<a href="#" class="close_dialog">Nope, Get this out of the way</a>
```

You could use this bit if jquery:

`$('.close_dialog').live('click', function(){ 
$('.DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox').remove();
});`

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Hi BaronVonKaneHoffen, Thanks so much for chiming in. I'm not using Jquery (I'm just now learning PHP, MySql and JS and haven't YET delved into JQuery) The problem I am experiencing now is that once I close the box, then scroll the box reappears. I do call the function in the body tag onscroll but isn't there a way I can make the box only appear once. (after clicking close, it should remain hidden for the visitor's duration of visit) Thanks again!!

Comment: Np. Get on jQuery though! While it's great to learn how to do this type of thing without it, it will make your life a lot easier in the long run :)

Answer (score 0):

you can make button inside div2 and add onClick attribute like this:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none'">Close</button>
```