# Second Part to Dialog Closing

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

This is a 2nd thread of a first I started here: [I Created A Dialog, Now How Can I Close It?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527866/i-created-a-dialog-now-how-can-i-close-it/15528095?noredirect=1#comment21997201_15528095)

I'm creating a new thread so I can include updated code.

First of all I'd like to give an enormous THANKS to all whom have helped me in the post linked above but as I stated, I'm starting this thread so I can add code samples.

I have a dialog on some of my pages that appears onscroll but I'm having some trouble.

This dialog can be seen here: (The semi transparent box that appears) http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/detail.php?fatherID=37&TypeID=42&ListingID=42

On detail.php I have:
(in the head)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loaddiv(thediv, thefile) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject ('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById(thediv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open('GET', thefile, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

Below That:

```
    <body onscroll="loaddiv('div2', 'do-you-have-a-dirt-bike-for-sale.html')">
```

Then:

```
    if (!Has_Seen_DB_For_Sale_Dialog($user_ip)){
        echo "<div id='div2'></div>";
        ip_add($user_ip);
    }
```

Above that (in an include file) I have:

```
    function Has_Seen_DB_For_Sale_Dialog($ip){
        global $user_ip;
        $query ="SELECT `IP` FROM `DB_For_Sale_Dialog` WHERE `IP`='$user_ip'";
        $query_run = mysql_query($query);

        $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
        if($query_num_rows==0){
            return false;
            }   else if($query_num_rows==1){
            return true;
        }
    }

    function ip_add($ip){
        $query = "INSERT INTO `DB_For_Sale_Dialog` VALUES('', '$ip') ";
        @$query_run = mysql_query($query);
    }
```

And the file that is displayed looks like:

```
<div id='div2'>
    <div class="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox" id="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox">
    <h2>Got A Dirt Bike You Want to Sell?</h2>
    <p class="DirtBikeForSaleBannerButton">
    <a href="http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/add.php">Yea, Show Me How</a>
    </p>

    <p class="DirtBikeForSaleBannerButtonNoThanks">
    <a onclick="javascript:var div = document.getElementById('div2');div.parentNode.removeChild(div);">Nope, Get This Out of The Way</a></p> 
    </div>
    </div>
```

I'm VERY Grateful of the help provided me in my last thread and mean NO disrespect in starting a new thread but What I'm now having trouble with is:

When I hover over the right button to close the box, the pointer doesn't turn into a hand as it does with other links.

When the dialog box is closed and the page is scrolled, the box reappears. (the function to display the box is called onscroll but I only want the box to appear ONCE.

If anyone wouldn't mind commenting on this I'd be most appreciative and I certainly look forward to your responses.

Thanks So Much,
Stuart K

Comment: please *edit* your original question, not post it again.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I had started a new thread as the 1st was cluttered and my question has matured to a more advanced question than that of the initial post

Answer (score 0):

Use this aproach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loaddiv(thediv, thefile) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject ('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById(thediv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            window.onscroll = null;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', thefile, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

--------I made this little test--------------

```
function loaddiv() {
alert('hiiii');
window.onscroll = null;

        }
```

The body call:

```
<body onscroll="loaddiv();">
```

And works just once xD

Saludos.

Comment: Hi again Robert, First of all, HUGE Thanks For The Help!! I've been away from my desk so I haven't YET implemented the code you provided but lemme run this idea by you... (before I do as a "Best Practice") What if I made the first function to be called in the body tag onscroll that was a function which checked if a visitor's IP is present BEFORE reaching any JS or AJAX?? Im gonna get this dialed in and working perfectly with ya'll on my side. I Love This Place!!

Comment: ALERT: I'm open for any comments on which method of displaying this black bar would be considered a "Best Practice" among professional webmasters??

Comment: In you page you should save the ip in a mysql DB....when a user visit your page then check for the ip...if doesnt exist in the database then write the function script and the onscroll call.....saludos ;)